# How to pause Observable?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am working on my first Angular 2 product. I created this `Observable.timer` and then subscribed to it. It polls the server for data.

How do I pause and unpause this?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.poll = Observable.timer(500,500).subscribe((t: any) => {
      this.request.getRackList(+this.global.zoneId).subscribe(
        incoming => this.import(incoming),
        err => { this.global.err(err) }
      );
    })
    this.canOpenClose = (this.global.mode === 2);
  }
```

Comment: The alternative is described here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1542

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to pause an Observable. You could:

- Unsubscribe / resubscribe when needed
- `.filter()` out emissions when paused
- create a [connectable Observable](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect) so you can pause / start emissions to all subscribers

Comment: I really liked this talk https://youtu.be/3LKMwkuK0ZE great place for knowledge is http://reactivex.io or http://rxmarbles.com

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here : [RxJS - pause, upon resume give last paused value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077300/rxjs-pause-upon-resume-give-last-paused-value)

Basically, you use the `switchMap` operator to stop the timer emissions/restart them and a pauser subject to emit a boolean indicating whether you want to pause or restart.
If you don't need the latest value, you can replace `publishReplay` by `publish`